# How can I run .http files without IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

IntelliJ and VS Code support a "editor-based REST client" that allows you to write and save HTTP requests in a file and execute them ([example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html)).
I think it would be a good idea to include something like this in a project for a REST API so developers can see various endpoints and test them without leaving the editor, but I don't want to tie them to a specific IDE.

**Is it possible to run .http files without requiring my team members adopt IntelliJ or VSCode?**

Answer (score 10):

If you are using VS Code you can use httpYAC. It is compatible with the IntelliJ http-Client.

Comment: httpYAC is also great compared to the REST Client extension (the current most popular REST client on the VS Code store) as it can run the entire file like IntelliJ's REST client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restcli:
https://github.com/restcli/restcli

A missing commandline application for execute IntelliJ HTTP Client file.

Comment: The Repo has been Archieved , so might not be applicable here